# SQL multiply 2 columns 2 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

What i am trying to do is calculate diner_payment_due (`DINER TABLE`), by multiplying food_serve_cost (`FOOD_SERVE TABLE`) by food_serve_size (`FS_DINER TABLE`)

```
CREATE TABLE diner (
diner_no            NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
diner_payment_due   NUMBER(6,2) NOT NULL,
diner_seat_no       NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
diner_seated        DATE NOT NULL,
diner_completed     DATE,
table_no            NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE food_serve (
food_item_no           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,   
food_serve_size        CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
food_serve_kilojoules  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
food_serve_cost        NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL
);


 CREATE TABLE FS_DINER (
 DINER_NO NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
 FOOD_ITEM_NO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 FOOD_SERVE_SIZE CHAR(2 BYTE) NOT NULL,
 FS_DINER_NO_SERVES NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
 FS_DINER_ITEM_SERVED CHAR (1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_fs_diner PRIMARY KEY (DINER_NO, FOOD_ITEM_NO,FOOD_SERVE_SIZE)
 );
```

I just need to return a single values and then insert into the diner table, i'm thinking that I need to do a `Inner Join`, then simply `sum (food_serve_cost * NO_SERVES)` then `group by DINER_NO` ?

`INSERT INTO DINER ( DINER_NO, DINER_PAYMENT_DUE, DINER_SEAT_NO, DINER_SEATED, DINER_COMPLETED, TABLE_NO) INSERT INTO DINER VALUES (1, SELECT SUM (FOOD_SERVE.FOOD_SERVE_COST * FS_DINER..., , 1, 1/05/2017, 1 /05/2017, 1);`

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this, and what have you tried so far?  Are you trying to find this for all entries at once, or just for a specific one?

Comment: just oracle sql, i just need to return a single values and then insert into the diner table, im thinking that i need to do a inner join, then simply sum (food_serve_cost * NO_SERVES) then group by DINER_NO ?                                  
      INSERT INTO DINER ( DINER_NO, DINER_PAYMENT_DUE, DINER_SEAT_NO, DINER_SEATED,
        DINER_COMPLETED, TABLE_NO)
       INSERT INTO DINER VALUES (1, SELECT SUM 
    (FOOD_SERVE.FOOD_SERVE_COST * FS_DINER...,  , 1, 
      1/05/2017, 
    1 /05/2017, 1);

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Am updating diner table based on the value from other two tables.

```
INSERT INTO DINER 
  (SELECT fs.diner_no, 
          (fs.food_serve_cost * fd.FOOD_SERVE_SIZE),
          11,sysdate,sysdate,11 /*Am assuming, Due to Not null constraint, there will be error*/
     FROM food_serve fs,
           FS_DINER fd
     WHERE fs.food_item_no = fd.food_item_no)
```